# How to fix a datetime restriction problem in a sql query?

Tags: sql

I'm developing a SQL Query, as a restriction, I want that the query returns data from the first day of the last month until now.

For example: If the query is executed today, the query will only return data entered from 01/03/2019 until today.

To do this, i created the following restriction:

```
...
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT>=concat(YEAR(GETDATE()),'0',month(GETDATE())-1,'01') AND
...
```

**The problem is in the months 01, 11 and 12:**

If the month is "11", the algorithm will return "1901001" and not "191001".

If the month is "01", the algorithm will return "190001" and not "181201".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you using `getdate()`?  It is not supported in MySQL.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

```
SF1010.F1_DTDIGT BETWEEN $yourDate AND date_add($yourDate,interval -DAY($yourDate)+1 DAY)
```

This gets dates between your date and the first day of the month. first day logic works by subtracting the DAY part to get first of month.

Answer (score 0):

This query will do the comparison of your `DTDIGIT` with the first day of the previous month in the `DATE` format:

`SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),'-',MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),'-','1'), '%Y-%m-%d')`

**Explanation**

- `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` returns the date exactly one month ago. We use that date to get the previous month
- `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions use the date explained above
- `STR_TO_DATE()` function converts a string representing a date to the
  MySQL `DATE` format, using the mask (in this example, it's
  `'%Y-%m-%d'`).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SF1010.F1_DTDIGT >= date_add(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day), interval -1 month)
```

This assumes the date is not in the future.  You can add another condition if that is possible.

If you happen to be using SQL Server, you can do this weird form of date arithmetic:

```
SF1010.F1_DTDIGT  >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
```